# Easy way to find un-excavated antiquity sites and shipwrecks?

Tags: civilization-6

In a recent game, when I revealed antiquity sites, I was notified of one in my territory underneath a district I had already constructed. I was able to excavate this with an archaeologist. However, even playing with resource icons on, the district "covered up" the antiquity site, so I had no indication other than the notification for discovering a new strategic resource in my territory.

The terrain tooltip correctly listed the site, but it would be extremely tedious to hover over every district, wonder, and city center tile on the map looking for additional sites. Is there any other way to list all remaining sites?

Comment: If you like to use mods, there are a few that add extra lenses. One of them is for the Archeologist and will highlight unexcavated sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version of the game (Gathering Storm expansion), if you select an Archeologist then all antiquity sites will be highlighted by a white border (Great People will do the same with tiles they need to be activated on).

I am not sure if they have patched this into the original version, or if it requires the expansion packs.